# O inicializador de tipo de 'X' acionou uma exceção

Tags: c#, exceção

Ao tentar executar a linha mais abaixo, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

***An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Programa.exe but was not handled in user code.
     Additional information: O inicializador de tipo de 'Programa.Constantes' acionou uma exceção.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.***

```
var fileMoveTrash = Path.Combine(Constantes.CaixaTrash, mensagem.Name);
```

Onde, "Constantes.CaixaTrash" vem da classe Constantes:

```
static class Constantes
 {
   (...)
    public static string CaixaTrash = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CaixaTrashPath"];
   (...)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema, tal como diz a excepção, esta na inicialização da classe `Constantes`.

Verifique que `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CaixaTrashPath"]` existe.

Caso não exista, vai ser gerada uma excepção, que não sendo tratada, vai ser transformada numa excepção do tipo `TypeInitializationException` pelo `runtime`. Isto acontece porque não foi possível inicializar a variável `CaixaTash`.

Se não tiver forma de garantir que "CaixaTrashPath" existe, uma solução pode passar por definir um constructor estático explicito e tentar extrair o valor:

```
public static string CaixaTrash;

static Constantes()
{
    try
    {
        CaixaTrash = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CaixaTrashPath"];
    }
    catch(Exception ex) // E boa ideia tentar apanhar um tipo de excepcao mais especifico.
    {
        CaixaTrash = string.Empty;
        // ou
        throw new Exception("CaixaTrashPath nao encontrado")
    }
}
```

Note que definir um constructor estático explicito não vai afectar outros campos estáticos que tenha. Segundo a especificação de C#:

> Se um constructor estático (§10.12) existir na classe, a inicialização 
>   dos campos estáticos ocorre imediatamente antes de da invocação do constructor 
>   estático. Caso contrario, a inicialização dos campos estáticos e executada antes do
>   primeiro uso de campo estático dessa classe.

Isto explica ainda a razão pela qual a excepção só é levantada quando usa o `Path.Combine`.

**==Nota extra==**

Prefira usar propriedades estáticas ao invés de campos estáticos. Dessa forma garante o controlo sobre a leitura e escrita. [Resposta no SOEN sobre o assunto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295109/1242661)

Comment: Obrigado Omni. Na verdade, havia outro item(frequencia) no AppSettings que não foi declarado. Mesmo sem fazer menção a ele, o erro era levantado ao se tentar utilizar o 'CaixaTrashPath' que existia.

Comment: @SantanaFire tal como explica na especificação do C#, se esse outro item também era um campo estático de Constantes, quando usava `CaixaTrash` pela primeira vez, todos os campos estáticos eram inicializados, dai o outro campo falhar.